# Multiply two columns in panda's dataframe and create a new column containing the solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe element in the following format: 
columns: Index, ISIN, Carbon Footprint, Market Value

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc4Jm.png)

I would like to calculate the product of Carbon footprint and market value for each row and add the result to a new column next to market value. Any ideas how this can work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, welcome to stacloverflow! Could you please provide a code snippet illustrating your problem? Pictures are not very practical. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Result] = df['Carbon Footprint'] * df['Market Value']
```